# Exuberant Ctags during active development

Tags: vim, ctags

Quick ctags question. Google did not reveal the answer. Ctags is awesome to browse a complete source file. But what about a file that is currently being worked on. Is there a way to dynamically update the ctags file each time a new function/variable is added?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write an `autocmd` that is triggered after `x` seconds of inactivity or after each `<Esc>`:

```
autocmd CursorHold *.js :!ctags -R .
```

But it is a bit messy.

See `:help autocmd` for more information and a list of possible events.

Also see the [EasyTags](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3114) plugin (that I use), or [AutoTag](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1343), or [Indexer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3221) which are a lot cleaner and smarter.

Comment: At last, someone who isn't me suggested Indexer for the ctags management! =) thanks, and I just like to add some info: Indexer does aware about projects, but AutoTag does not. This means that you can work on several projects simultaneously, which could have the same symbols, and Indexer will handle it correctly (i.e. tags will not be mixed up). And, the second thing: tags are generated in background, so you can work on really large projects, and you have not to wait while ctags does generate your tags. Tested on Windows, Linux, MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

Also see the [TagList](http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/) plugin - the top-rated and most-downloaded plugin  ;)